# Creating ArcGIS report with multiple related tables?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, table, relationship-class, reports

Is there a way to create a report in ArcGIS 10.3 that includes data from multiple related tables in a file geodatabase?

I'll give an example using soil profile data. I have a point feature class representing soil cores. Each point has data specific to that site that the core was extracted from. This table has a common ID and a relationship class, with a one to many relation, with another table that has a separate record for each layer in the soil core as it gets further down the core. Is there a way to select one soil site point, make a report for that point with the ArcGIS report wizard, and include the soil horizon records for that point in the report?

Answer (score 3):

To create a report that includes data from multiple related tables, you'll have to create/modify a table that is going to join the different tables. So in your case, you can join your soil cores table to the table that has separate record for each layer in the soil core. With a SelectByAttributs, you can select all the features corresponding to a specific soil core and finally create a report for that soil core.

You can create a nice application with arcpy to accomplish this task.

Comment: That would work for the presented situation. It would get more difficult when I have more than one related tables, like if I also wanted to include records in another table describing above ground vegetation. I was hoping that Esri might have already built this in with the report wizard and I just couldn't see it.